# Replacing javascript nashorn:mozilla_compat.js use in ant script

Tags: javascript, java, build, ant, nashorn

Oracle has depreciated nashorn and I use it in my apache ant build scripts.

Here is a short example;

```
try{load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");}catch(e){;}
    importClass(java.io.File);
    var sourceName = project.getProperty("build.source.dir") + "/" +project.getProperty("teiFile") + ".xml";
    var targetName = project.getProperty("build.search.dir") + "/" + project.getProperty("teiFile") + ".xml";
    var sourceFile = new File("", sourceName);
    var targetFile = new File("", targetName);
    var uptodate = targetFile.exists() && sourceFile.lastModified() < targetFile.lastModified();
      var sourcePrefix = project.getProperty("teiFile");
      if(!uptodate & !sourcePrefix.startsWith("G")) {
         ......
       }
}
```

I've heard mentions of Rhino or graalVM as a replacement, but each seems to have a fairly long list of deficiencies.Suggestions for a library that is currently active and stable.

thanks, scott

Comment: While I don’t know what your `......` line represents, I suspect the parts you’ve shown can be done with regular Ant tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraalVM is currently active, stable, has a [Nashorn compatibility mode](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/NashornMigrationGuide.md#nashorn-compatibility-mode). 
You can run your ant scripts with GraalVM, and the JS engine is included by default. Or you can include GraalVM's JavaScript as a few dependencies and run on OpenJDK, which will be slower, and might be an untested combination of OpenJDK and GraalVM's JavaScript, but [can also work](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/RunOnJDK.md).

Comment: Specifically, you should probably set that to your ANT_OPTS before calling ant:

    `ANT_OPTS="-Dpolyglot.js.nashorn-compat=true" ant`

See our [FAQ](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/FAQ.md#my-application-used-to-run-on-nashorn-it-does-not-work-on-graalvm-javascript)