# Unable to create javax script engine for javascript in Extjs

Tags: java, extjs, ant, nashorn, graalvm

It seems that the Nashorn engine has been removed since JDK15 https://openjdk.org/jeps/372 But I don't want to downgrade the JDK to build the Sencha app. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

I also found some articles, it seems to relate to the ant `<script>` tag, someone suggested using GraalVM, but I'm not sure how to integrate this thing.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64469 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60515528/21004428

Someone suggested importing the Nashorn engine and its dependency, I added nashorn-core-15.4.jar, asm-9.4.jar, asm-util-9.4.jar and asm-commons-9.4.jar to a build.xml, it works. But there are too many build.xml (including Sencha's xml) files in the app, not sure how to set them all.
[Engine & dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R37ww.png)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75097969/21004428