# Sencha Cmd - Unable to create javax script engine for javascript in Extjs - after upgrade to Java 17

Tags: extjs, java-17, sencha-cmd

After upgrading the java to the 17 version the sencha cmd does not run and I get

> "Unable to create javax script engine for javascript in Extjs"

Using the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282644/unable-to-create-javax-script-engine-for-javascript-in-extjs) I added the mentioned jar into classpath of sencha commander, but that is not a good solution. I am looking for another way to put them on the classpath, no result. Does anyone know where I could put these properties? I am trying to use sencha.vmoption for this, but don';t know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Ext JS 7.7 & CMD 7.7 does not support Java 17 version. Officially Sencha supports Java 8 & 11 only - https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.7.0/guides/getting_started_cmd.html#getting_started_cmd_-_dependencies

It been notified in discord channel that Sencha is working on 7.8 to support Java 17 and 21 versions.